# Is my question about search on a web site suitable anywhere on SE?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My question is:

> I frequently use a search box on a particular website. I would like to
>   search for an exact phrase in this search box. However when I try the
>   standard double quote "" used in Google Search box I get no results.
>   This indicates to me that this particular search box does not support
>   the double quote syntax. How may I uncover the syntax that this search
>   box is using to extract the results I desire?

I have already tried to probe the receptivity of this question on Meta Stack Overflow. It seems this question would be off topic on Stack Overflow: [Possible to ask this question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314256/possible-to-ask-this-question-on-stack-overflow/314257#314257)

As the user in the link suggested, I will try the WebApps page but first I would like to see if I can find a more relevant SE community for this question.  Is there any Stack Exchange site where this question would be on-topic and appropriate?

Comment: I run through the [all sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) but didn't find anything that would be related. I'm even not quite sure if WebApps is suitable for this. Maybe request a new one in the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *possible* that you'd get help on Web Apps. Look at their [tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags), search a bit - do you see the name of the site/app you're looking for? Then there's a good chance they might be able to help.

If not, you're free to ask there, but keep in mind that Web Apps is a support community for *applications* that just happen to run in your browser. If your question is about how search works on an average informational site - then it's pretty likely to be something to ask the operators of the site you're using.

If people commonly go to this site and search it in order to get a specific kind of work done, then you're *probably* okay. Just tag the question with the name of the site (or leave a note in a comment under your question that you'd appreciate the tag being created if you don't have enough rep).

If it's someone's personal site that isn't running on a common platform, or a 'corporate presence' kind of site, then you're probably better off just asking the people that operate it.